# Algebraic manipulation problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was just wondering out of curiosity since i do not see how this could be done but is there a potential way to make $a $ the subject of this formula?

$$X=\bigg(\frac{50\times2}{a^{50\times2}}-1\bigg)a^y-\bigg(\frac{50\times2}{a^{50\times2}}-1\bigg)$$

Where $X\in[0,100]$ and $y\in [0,100]$.

Would appreciate the suggestions and help offered.

EDIT: What if the equation is given as:
$$X=\bigg(\frac{50\times2}{a^{50\times2}-1}\bigg)a^y-\bigg(\frac{50\times2}{a^{50\times2}-1}\bigg)$$

Comment: As the Wolfram Development Platform can't find a solution, I'm guessing your only option is to find $a$ numerically.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, so what  numerical analysis techniques could we employ?

Comment: Do you have an interval in which $a$ must lie?

Comment: There is no information given on the interval of $a$.

Comment: Why do you write $50 \times 2$? Do you just mean 100?

Comment: Hmm. That makes things a bit harder. I think I'd still start with the binary search algorithm, as it's super-stable and doesn't require the derivative. You'll have to have a specific $X$ and $y$ in mind to run any numerical algorithm, though. Also, you'll need to find an interval by trial and error that contains a root.

Comment: Also, rewriting the equation as $$x = \frac{(a^{100} - 100) (1 - a^y )}{a^{100}}$$ might help.

Comment: @Adrian Keister i changed the question alittle, could you help me please?